# Does Yii framework 2.0 provide any view helper that can generate checkbox list with input text field as last option?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, checkboxlist

To generate a checkboxlist within Yii framework 2.0 I use the following line of code.

```
Html::checkboxList($model->choises, null, $arrayOption, ['separator' => '<br />',]);
```

I would like to have the last checkbox option with an input text field like `others`. Does Yii framework 2.0 provide any view helper to generate that?

Comment: No. You can extend yii\helpers\Html and create a new method

Comment: @SiZE thanks for your comment. Please check my solution I came up with which I answered my own question here.

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed to approach this goal I have tried different solution and came up with an ideal solution which I would like to share here since no one yet could answer this question. The solution is for both `radionList` and `checkboxList`.

Just inject the `$arrayOption` with the following code snippet.

```
$arrayOption[0] = 'Others <input type="text" class="my-class-name" name="MyModel[my_other_option]">';
```

Add the following code into the `rules` function inside of the `model` class.

```
[
    ['my_other_option',], 'required' , 'when' => function($model) {
                return $model->choises == '0';
    },
],
```

By doing so, the validation will be failed when you selected the `Other` option but didn't fill in the input text field, named `my_other_option`.